# Get all product's elements (BOM) to make another one on Odoo 11 enterprise

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

I need to get all product's elements to make another one. For example, I have a product template `computer` which has variant `hp` which needs a `screen`, `keyboard` ... And another variant `asus` needs only "screen" (don't need `keyboard`). I need to get all product's elements to make my `Asus` product.To do it i have this code :

```
class Product(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.product'
    def get_all_bom_products(self):
        for product in self:
            missing_components = product.bom_ids.mapped('bom_line_ids.product_id')
```

With this code, when it's the loop turn of `hp` product, i got the good elements of the product (`screen` and `keyboard`). When it's the turn of `asus` product, i got the same elements of the product (`screen` and `keyboard`) instead only `screen`.
Working on :

Odoo 11.0+e (Enterprise Edition)

Comment: Are you using multilevel BOM?

Comment: Yes I use multilevel BOM